# Testing for significant changes month to month

Tags: t-test

Can I simply use a paired student's t-test to check for significant changes from month to month?

Comment: Sure, but you should use a multiple comparison test to control for the Type I error rate.

Comment: so an ANOVO then followed up by a poc hoc test.  The problem is or would be  I only have access to the data at the end of the month.  So I guess I could do both.  Each moth a paired t-test followed up with an Anova as monthly data  starts to accumulate....

Comment: Are you familiar with the contrasts?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an ongoing project, where you need to identify the time when the mean (for instance) of the process changes?  If so, you should look up either changepoint models or else hidden Markov chains.  In particular, if this is a sequential problems it won't be dealt with well by the usual multiple comparison approaches (which assume a fixed number of comparisons).

Comment: Ongoing project.